# Можно ли вызывать draw на view внутри другого view?

Tags: swift

Есть такой код:

```
@IBDesignable
class Test: UIView {
   override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
       let view = UIView()
       view.backgroundColor = .red
       view.draw(rect)
   }
}
```

Но View ничего не отображает. Если рисовать какую то фигуру внутри draw через, например UIBezierPath, все будет отображаться. У меня предположение, что вызывать draw внутри другого draw - ошибка

Answer (score 1):

Напрямую вызывать метод `draw` не нужно, для перерисовки содержимого вью используется метод `setNeedsDisplay()`, который уже сам вызывает `draw` ([док](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622437-setneedsdisplay))

```
view.setNeedsDisplay()
```